# Dataframe - how to run calculations without using for loop?

Tags: python, numpy, dataframe

I have a pandas DataFrame

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [10,20,30], "B": [20, 30, 10], "C": [20, 30, 10]})
```

```
df
    A   B  C
0   10  20 20
1   20  30 30
2   30  10 10
```

and another ndarray `w = array([0.2, 0.3, 0.4])`

how do I add column `D` such that its value is dot product of each row and `w`

i.e. the value for `D[0]` will be `np.dot(df.iloc[0],w) = 16`

likewise, value for `D[1]` is 25 (`np.dot(df.iloc[1],w) = 25`.

(I am thinking `apply()` function but not sure how to use it, using for loop might be inefficient)

thanks,

Answer (score 4):

You can do that by using the [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) over rows (`axis = 1`) from pandas.DataFrame

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [10,20,30], "B": [20, 30, 10], "C": [20, 30, 10]})
>>> w = np.array([0.2, 0.3, 0.4])
>>> df["D"] = df.apply(lambda p: np.dot(p.values, w), axis=1)
>>> df
    A   B   C     D
0  10  20  20  16.0
1  20  30  30  25.0
2  30  10  10  13.0
```

Although, for efficiency sake, you probably are better off turning the dataframe into a ndarray, and use matrix multiplication with [`matmul`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html) from numpy.

```
df["D"] = np.matmul(df.values, w)
```

Comment: perfect! yeh I think I had a brain freeze but that's what I was after. thanks again.

Comment: thanks I like the edit better. now to make it a bit complicated - what if I had separate W for each row?

Comment: You could either pandas apply, and do the dot product with the corresponding array, or numpy matmul and then get the diagonal of the matrix. Performance-wise I have no idea which one is better. Example: https://repl.it/repls/PrivateBubblyOrganization

Comment: Another approach would be to use something similar to what @FBruzzesi is suggesting. If your `df` as the same shape as `w2`, you can directly multiply them, and sum all the rows like this: `(df * w2).sum(axis=1)`

Comment: thanks that was really useful, my original problem is a lot more complex, I have about 2000 different Ws each of 9*9 dimensions and the df is about 2000 * 9! I liked the matmul approach but will have to tailor to my needs given the size

Comment: btw what if my W was a 3*3 dimension (ie W1 = np.random.rand(3,3), W2 = W1*2, W3 = W2*2) and the value of D is calculated as np.dot(row, np.dot(W,rowT). how would you incorporate that using your suggested formula.

Comment: @PrasKam The apply solution is a possibility, another way would be to prepare the matrices for matmul, expanding `W` to have duplicated rows (`W'`), and then just `df * W' * df.T`. I had my fair share of handling big matrices multiplications (mainly in R, not python) and for these, the languages themselves are rather slow, compared to the functions implemented underneath (in libraries like numpy). I found myself having performance boosts when preparing the data, and then send it to one of the functions, minimizing the functions I'd use in python/R.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use a vectorize approach exploiting  [numpy broadcast](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html):

```
df['D'] = np.sum(df.to_numpy() * w), axis=1)
'''
.to_numpy() is from version 0.24 if I remember correctly, before use .values
'''

df
    A   B   C     D
0  10  20  20  16.0
1  20  30  30  25.0
2  30  10  10  13.0
```

Doing perfomance analysis in spyder editor using `%timeit`, here what I got ordered from slowest to fastest:

```
%timeit (df * w).sum(axis=1)
2.15 ms ± 590 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit df.apply(lambda p: np.dot(p.values, w), axis=1)
900 µs ± 76.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit np.sum((df.to_numpy() * w), axis=1)
19.2 µs ± 481 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Comment: thanks @FBruzzesi, that was helpful. my original problem is a lot more complex. I have about 2000 different Ws each of 9*9 dimensions and the df is about 2000 * 9!

Comment: That's when speed is important :)

Comment: btw what if my W was a 3*3 dimension (ie  W1 = np.random.rand(3,3), W2 = W1*2, W3 = W2*2) and the value of D is calculated as np.dot(row, np.dot(W,rowT). how would you incorporate that using your suggested formula. I think I am able to get it using .apply() but curious to know if there is a faster way to do that.

Comment: so individual rows will gave its own W for calculations.

Comment: I think it is possible to use broadcasting anyway, however it gets messy and hard to debug really quickly, while `np.dot(row, np.dot(W,rowT)` is immediate to understand.